# $(window).load(function() problem in my ajax page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am displaying booking form in parent page from a ajax page.
In that ajax page there is  `$(window).load(function() {`.

if i run that ajax page directly in the browser, `$(window).load(function()` is working fine.
If i cal the ajax page from my parent page, then `$(window).load(function()` is not working.

I don't need  `$(document).ready(function()`. I need `$(window).load(function()` as i am doing some image manipulation.

Please help me in this.

Comment: What's an "ajax page"? How do you "call" it? If you quote the code a bit more, we'll probably be able to figure out what's going wrong, but this isn't enough information to work with.

Comment: $(window).load() won't work unless you use iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do loading detection on the image(s) that load from the AJAX page. Something like this called after the ajax content is loaded:

```
var total_images = $(".target-div img").length;
var loaded_images = 0;
$(".target-div img").each(function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
        // this img tag is loaded
        loaded_images++;
        if(loaded_images == total_images) {
            // Horray! all images are loaded
            // do something here...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  // First we wait until the document is completely loaded using the handy
  // jQuery "ready" method.
  $(window).load(function() {
 // No we can paint our canvas. Something rounded with a shadow ;-)
 $("#main-outer").liquidCanvas(
  "gradient{from:#<?=$gradient1?>; to:#<?=$gradient2?>;} => roundedRect{radius:10},[shadow border{color:#fff}] => roundedRect{radius:10}");
  
  });
</script>
i am using jquery liquid canvas plugin. It will give gradient and round corner effect to my DIV. this im using in my ajax page. i need to call this page from my parent page.